# Proof of UNIQUE SOLUTION- to $x^TAy=f^{T}y$ for any $y\in \mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Define the bilinear bounded and elliptic map: $B:\mathbb{R^n}\times \mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ as follows: $B(x,y)=x^{T}Ay$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. Consider the functional $G:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by: $G(y)=f^Ty$ where $f\in \mathbb{R^n}$. Show that there exists unique solution to $x=x^*$ to: $B(x,y)=G(y)$ for any $y\in \mathbb{R^n}$.

I appreciate anyone who spares some time to help me with either/both parts! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is A invertible? And is there any condition on f? If A = 0 and f != 0 the question 1 is wrong, you probably forgot something.

Comment: @Thomas: I included the original problem in the original statement.

Comment: The way the question is posed, it seems we want to show Q1 for A positive definite, and then in Q2 show that positive definiteness is not necessary. Right? That would also cover @Thomas 's comment. But that is not obvious from the "original problem".

Comment: @megas: The original question asks a proof without assuming that the bilinear form $B$ is symmetric (i.e, without assuming that the matrix A is symmetric).

Comment: @M.Krov I saw the edit. But then Q2 does not make sense to me, because it is already covered by Q1. Plus the issue raised in Thomas's comment still stands.

Comment: @megas: here is the link to the book where I found the question. I hope I didn't miss any details. It is problem 3.9 from the book: "Finite Element Solution of Boundary Value Problems: Theory and Computation
 By O. Axelsson, V. A. Barke".  https://books.google.ca/books?id=AKTiBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA141&dq=assumption+of+coerciveness+is+by+no+means+necessary+for+the+problem+to+have+a+unique+solution&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IL8YVa7PA-iIsQSXiYGgDQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=assumption%20of%20coerciveness%20is%20by%20no%20means%20necessary%20for%20the%20problem%20to%20have%20a%20unique%20solution&f=false

Comment: @M.Krov ok, the book has the coerciveness assumption in Q1 and lifts that assumption in Q2. Coerciveness is a sufficient condition for A to have full rank. I was confused because you mentioned positive definiteness in the second question, and I thought this had to be an assumption for the first part.

Comment: @megas: I thought coerciveness of the bilinear map $B$ means that the matrix $A$ is positive definite. Am I wrong? So, what should I do to edit the statement of the problem?

Comment: @M.Krov I had to check the definition of coerciveness in wikipedia myself :).  In my mind, positive definite refers to a symmetric matrix. If A was symmetric, then I agree that coercive bilinear form would be equivalent to positive definite. But from the definition I see, coerciveness does not require A to be symmetric, so it is more general that positive definiteness. But maybe I am wrong, so don't take it for granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** *(for the first part)*:
Since the map is coercive, we know that $\mathbf{A}$ has full rank (why?). 
Choose your favourite $n$ linearly independent vectors $\mathbf{y}_{1}, \dots, \mathbf{y}_{n}$ and form the matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ using these vectors as columns. 
By assumption, $\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}_{i} = \mathbf{f}^{T}\mathbf{y}_{i}$, $\forall i\in [n]$.
Equivalently, 
$\mathbf{x}^{T}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{f}^{T}\mathbf{Y}$. 
How many solutions does this linear system have?

**Edit** *(for the second part)* I think you can take $\mathbf{A}$ to be any full rank $n \times n$ matrix, without necessarily positive eigenvalues. Then you can use the previous argument, which only used the fact that $\mathbf{A}$ has full rank.

Comment: I just need to know how you prove that if the map is coercive, then $A$ has a full rank. Of course, if I know that, then I can choose $y_i=e_i$, and then I get a linear system of equations of the form $AU=B$

Comment: According to wikipedia, a self-adjoint operator $\mathbf{A}: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is called coercive if there exists a constant $c>0$ such that
$\langle \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle \ge c\|\mathbf{x}\|^2$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. 
If $\mathbf{A}$ does not have full rank, then there exists non-zero $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\langle \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle = \langle \mathbf{0},\mathbf{x}\rangle =  0$.

Comment: That makes sense! For the second part, how do I show that coerciveness of the map is NOT a NECESSARY Condition? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I appreciate if you can help me with the second part! Thanks!

Comment: @M.Krov Edited answer.